# What should I do with two potted Silver Maples that are about a year and a half old?

Tags: tree-care, maple

We sold our home last July and we had two beautiful Silver Maples in the yard and early in the spring of 2022 I took two seeds and planted them in separate buckets. They sprouted through the summer and grew to about 18 inches. Ultimate plan with all of this was to put these two new trees at our new home we are building.

Last fall, I moved them to larger pots and then I buried them in the ground under lots of sand and then put mulch over the top and surrounded them with wire mesh to keep critters out over winter.

They emerged this spring in excellent shape and they have rapidly continued to grow in the pots I moved them to last fall.Right now they are both about 49 inches tall.

Here is the problem, I am currently living three hundred miles from where these trees will eventually be planted. We will not be moved into our new home until spring of 2024.If I take them down to our lot and plant them now, I won't be able to monitor them and make sure they continue to thrive and I feel they would absolutely get eaten or destroyed since we will not be there.

So am I alright to keep these in pots and do the same thing over the winter to protect the roots? Since they have gotten so big this summer, should I upgrade them to larger pots one more time?

I would then transplant them for good next spring to their permanent home.

Comment: You can repeat your system. But saplings are not newborns needing intensive care, and can be planted now at the new house, 20' away. A cage or coil are not bad ideas.